# How to get pick up location(Current) in android uber sdk

Tags: android, sdk, uber-api

I know in general how to get address,lat and log for current location(pick up) in android,But what I am looking is Uber API which gives me current(Pick up) location.

In Following is code where I am passing lat and long of pick up location it works fine,

```
RideParameters rideParametersForProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
                        .setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
                        .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
                        .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
                        .build();
```

Below code where I am trying to get current pick up location using uber sdk API but its not working,

```
RideParameters rideParametersForProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
                    .setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
                    .setPickupToMyLocation()
                    .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
                    .build();
```

**setPickupToMyLocation()** is not setting pick up(Current)location as expected.

**Note:-** But in IOS uber sdk giving current location.
Below IOS Code RideParameter with current location.

```
(UBSDKRideParameters *)_buildRideParameters {

        UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];

        [builder setPickupToCurrentLocation];
        if (self.dropAddrs != nil) {
            [builder setDropoffLocation:self.dropAddrs];
        }
        //  NSLog(@"Drop Address:%@",self.dropAddrs);
        return [builder build];
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to utilize the embedded request screen or a deeplink into the Uber app?

Comment: have you found an answer?